# Regex match for a string in a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I feel like there is too much repetitive code going on here. All I am doing is doing a basic regex match for a string in the URL.

If a match is found, I find a `li` with a class (`.index`, `.grid` or `.type`) and add the active class. This is just for my main `nav` in an attempt to make it somewhat dynamic.

However, I feel like there is a more efficient way to code this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var myLocation = window.location.href;
  var index = /index/i;
  var grid = /grid/i;
  var type = /type/i;
  var urlIndex = convertURL.match(index);
  var urlGrid = convertURL.match(grid);
  var urlType = convertURL.match(type);
  
  if (urlIndex) {
    $('.index').addClass('active');
  } else if (urlGrid) {
    $('.grid').addClass('active');
  } else if (urlType) {
    $('.type').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Much like elclanrs' solution, just slightly more "plain"

```
$(function () {
  var classes = ['index', 'grid', 'type'],
      url = window.location.href.toLowerCase();
  for(var i = 0, l = classes.length ; i < l ; i++ ) {
    if(url.indexOf(classes[i]) !== -1) {
      $('.' + classes[i]).addClass('active');
      break; // only first matching class is considered
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: so without the break, all the li's would get the class "active" right?

Comment: @user3259232 All the ones with a class matching the URL would, yes. E.g. `foo.com/bar/index/how-to-griddle.html` would activate the `index` and `grid` items, but not the `type` ones..

Comment: @user3259232 Without the `break`, the code would work like a series of `if`s, instead of an `if.. else if` structure like your code. I.e. without the `break` a url like `example.com/index/grid/type/xyz` would cause it to act the same as `$(".index, .grid, .type").addClass("active")` because all three classes would get matched. But _with_ the `break`, only the first matching class will be considered, so it's like `$(".index").addClass("active")`

Comment: @Flambino My comment was an answer to user3259232's comment about removing the `break`.

Comment: @DavidHarkness Makes sense. Sorry - failed to read it in its proper context

Answer (score 3):

I think you meant `myLocation` in place of `convertURL`.

You don't need that many variables, a typical refactoring might look like this:

```
// Short version of $(document).ready(fn)
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  if (/index/i.test(loc)) {
    $('.index').addClass('active'); 
  } else if (/grid/i.test(loc)) {
    $('.grid').addClass('active');
  } else if (/type/i.test(loc)) {
    $('.type').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

But I would go for a less imperative solution, without the use of regex, for example:

```
$(function() {
  var loc = window.location.href;
  var classes = ['index', 'grid', 'type'];
  var isMatch = function(x){return loc.toLowerCase().indexOf(x)>-1};
  $('.'+ classes.filter(isMatch)[0]).addClass('active');
});
```

Note that you can go even further an cache the lowercased url, but you may want to use the original variable intact later in the code.

Comment: The first rewrite is missing the `else` part of the original `else if` tests. This could activate up to three items. In the second, you may as well convert the URL to lowercase when pulling it from `window.location.href` instead of repeating the process for every `indexOf` call.

Comment: @DavidHarkness: yes, I edited and made them `if` without realizing. And yes, I thought about doing `toLowerCase` above but OP might want to use the `url` in its original shape later on.

Comment: Keep in mind also that `Array.prototype.filter` is defined in ES5. You can use [es5-shim](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim) for older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // use single var per function, 
    // good for minimizing and other stuff
    var

    i,

    // new string literal, not String object
    convertURL = '' + window.location,

    // the array of strings keeps only the difference 
    // from the repetitive code
    classes = ['index', 'grid', 'type'],

    // using functions with proper arguments reduces repetitivness
    matches = function (regex) {
        return convertURL.match(new RegExp(regex, 'i'));
    }

    // var
    ;

    // always use += instead of ++ -> makes for clear intention
    for (i = 0; i < classes.length; i += 1) {
        if (matches(classes[i])) {
            // returning out of this function stops iteration
            return $('.' + classes[i]).addClass('active');
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: It seems a bit wasteful to use regex when a simple `indexOf` on the lowercased URL would suffice.

Comment: At this moment I don't see it as a concern because DOM manipulation is so much slower that it will negate all of the micro-optimizations :/